# Two DV's, help me please

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have an experiment where there is a control group and an experimental group and the iv is a mindfulness exercise. There are two dv, being a mindfulness score and a quiz score. T-test shows both dv are affected by iv IE mindfulness score and quiz score are increased by a mindfulness exercise. I can't figure out what to do to show the link between a high mindfulness score and a high quiz score. My spss skills are fairly limited but am wondering if it's a MANOVA problem?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CV.

Questions about coding are off topic, but MANOVA is certainly one way to approach this problem.